# Complicated Geometry for c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, math

This is pretty complicated I think. I need to get distance 1 and distance 2 in c# code. Only know data I have is the depth, midpoint, the lengths of the bottom line from the midpoint, and the 45-degree angles. Appreciate the help.

[image: My coding geometry problem]

Comment: How would you solve it with maths? What is the formula?

Comment: that's the complicated part I'm struggling with.

Comment: I suggest going to http://math.stackexchange.com/ they might have a good answer for you

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated.

Comment: Interesting problem nevertheless ;)